# How do I remove this PhpStorm inspection popup without disabling inspections?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am using PhpStorm because I really like the features, but I would like to disable this little popover to make it look cleaner. How would I do this without disabling the inspections themselves?

The popover:

[image: Ugly popover ;C]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove/disable it. You can only make it less visible (smaller). For that you need to configure it to be as in previous versions: hover over and use the menu there, as simple as that (`Compact View` option on the screenshot below).

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]