# PhpStorm move editor inspection icons from right to left

Tags: phpstorm

Anyone know if you can position the inspection icons/totals (the yellow warning triangles and the spellchecker) that are normally in the top *right* on the *left* instead?

Also, is there a way to increase the size of them?

(Reason: I use a wide-ish monitor. I struggle to make a habit of looking at them because my eyes have to move all the way across to the edge of the screen to do so. If they were on the left, they'd be in my eyeline a lot more. I tried moving the *Project* window to the right, with the editor on the left. That didn't really help…)

Comment: No. You cannot move it. Try "Problems" tool window -- it should list all found issues in a file as a list and you can place a tool window on the lest (instead of the default bottom)

Comment: @LazyOne nice idea, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move it. You can only make it smaller (so it only shows a coloured square: like it was back in 2020.2 and older versions: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64756369/783119 for that).

Try **Problems tool window** -- it should list all found issues in a file as a list and you can place it on the left to your editor (instead of the default bottom).

[image]